# OleDbAdapter is not recognizing '@' in query

Tags: c#, oledb

The following code is used to read data from excel into a gridview.

```
String cusid1 = maskedTextBox1.Text.ToString();
string s = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=c:xxx.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(s); // connection string
con.Open();
string strQuery = "select * from [test$] where cusid = @cusid1";
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, con);

//Or Use OleDbCommand
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

conn.Open();
```

But when specify a number in place of `@cusid1` like `select * from [test$] where cusid=1`, I am getting the correct output. If I use `@cusid` in the query I get this error:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: You are not adding `@cusid1` parameter to your command anywhere

Comment: Where do you expect to set the value for `@cusid1`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in the parameter. Also, named parameters don't do anything in OLEDB. They are ignored. Use `?` instead.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx):

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement

The code you need:

```
 string strQuery = "select * from [test$] where cusid = ?";

 OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cusid);

 da.SelectCommand = command;
```